# C++ diagrama de flujo desde código en VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

quisiera crear un diagrama de flujo en Visual Studio 2019(proyecto migrado desde VC++ 6.0) o encontrar alguna herramienta freeware/open source parecida a [Visustin](https://www.aivosto.com/visustin.html). No puedo pagar una licencia y el número de archivos que uso excede el del límite que imponen para el servicio gratuito.

He intentado generar el diagrama de flujo con el codemap de VS, pero no he sido capaz de crear algo parecido a lo que ofrece Visustin. Creo el diagrama de clases pero necesitaría crear el de secuencia.

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Hi, this site is in spanish, so you should translate your question or post it
in: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Oh, pensaba que estaba en la web en inglés. Siento la torpeza.

Comment: Pedir recomendaciones de recursos externos no encaja en el formato del sitio, lee  [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Por ese motivo tu 9regunta permanecerá cerrada

Comment: ¿Si la encajáramos en "herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores" que te parecería?

Comment: no es lo mismo.